# Is it possible to insert a Method into a List<>?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have tow lists. One has objects that a user has selected. The second will contain Methods that will be used on objects in the first list.

`List 1` `List2`

`Paul` `Method ShakeHand`

`Mark` `Method HighFive`

`Annie` `Method Hug`

I would use indexing to have Method 0 in List 2 use the object 0 in List 1.
They would continue to go down the list until each action is taken.

I've tried using `Add()` with the method inside with no luck.
I've also used Google with no luck as I'm not sure as to what terminology I should be using.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "delegate". In particular, look up [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.action.aspx)

Comment: If the methods have the same signature a delegate may be what you want to store in list 2.

Comment: use dictionery insead of two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Func<T1, T2, ..,  TReturn>` or `Action<T1, ... Tn>` delegates. The only catch is the methods would need to have the same signature.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by inserting an object — that is, an instance of a class.

Create a base class with a method named `Greet` or similar. Create subclasses that implement the `Greet` method and do a `ShakeHand`, `HighFive`, or `Hug`. Insert instances of the appropriate subclass, then call the `Greet` method when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

It all sounds a bit dynamic to me. I'd use reflection, both for populating the selection list with available methods, and for invocations - which leads us to the question of parameters. All of the proposed solutions assume that all the methods to be invoked will have the same signature. If that's true then any of these suggestions will work, with mine and Dmitry's requiring the least maintenance in order to add methods. Dmitry's version is better if you have a suitable version of the framework (but you'd still need reflection to populate your selection list).